Is 1 reputation enough for protecting a question?
I noticed Why is C++ still a very popular language in quantitative finance? was protected, presumably to stop a language war. I just wanted to point out that if you have another worthwhile Stack Overflow account you get 100 reputation just for joining.
So when the intention is to limit answers to "Quantitative Finance" regulars, maybe the minimum needs to be over 100?
(Having said that, the discussion I quoted seems to have been okay, so that might be overdoing the policing?)

The 1 Reputation requirement for protected questions is because we are a beta site. I didn't know at the time that protecting the question would have so little effect given our infancy status.

The reputation needs to have been earned on this site, not awarded for having an account on another site.  All those who have answered this question recently have asked or answered other questions on this site and been upvoted.  I, too, believe this question is getting far too much attention, but it's not horrible.
